# Outlines around segmented cells

Tags: matlab

The following lines, creates white rings (outlines) around my segmented cells

```
 se1 = strel('diamond',10);  se2 = strel('diamond',4);
 R = imdilate([RED],se1)&[~imdilate([RED],se2)];
 imshow(R)
```

And this line displays my segmented cells in RGB form.

```
    r = imadjust(mat2gray(RED));
    z = zeros(size(r),'like',r);
    r = cat(3,r,z,z);
    imshow(r)
```

Now, with a "hold on;" between two code, the outlines should be plotted around the red cells but it doesn't. I'm trying to plot white outlines around my segmented cells. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `r = imadjust(mat2gray(R));` instead of `r = imadjust(mat2gray(RED));`

Comment: No. R is the dilated outlines, and r is my RGB cells (with red color). When I run each of them separately, imshow(R) plots the white rings and imshow(r) displays the red cells. Now, I want to overlay them onto each other, so I just simply put "hold on;" between codes, but it still displays the red cells (imshow(r)).

r = imadjust(mat2gray(R)) will only show the rings in red color without the cells.

Comment: when you do `hold on` between `imshow`'s it replaces the previous image with a new one (actually it just covers it, but the effect is similar). try using `imoverlay` like: `rR = imoverlay(r,R);` and `imshow` that.

Comment: It worked :-) Thank you so much for the great points.